# Get type that already was deferred in template

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I've created a templated class, and it works fine:

( I'm using openCV library, so I have cv::Mat type of matrices)

```
template < class T, T V >
class MatFactory
{

  private:

    const T static VALUE = V;

  public:

    void create(/* some args */)
    {
      cv::Mat M;

      // filling the matrice with values V of type T

      // loop i,j
      M.at<T>(i,j) = V;

      return M;
    }
};
```

But later in code, I need to get an element of matrix M at some indexes (i,j). But how do I know the type T?

```
MatFactory<int, 1> MF;

// getting object
cv::Mat m = MF.create();

// then I need to get some value (with `.at<>` method)
int x = m.at<int>(2,3);

// But, it means I should every time explicitly declare INT type
// Can I somehow get the type, that was passed to template factory
// Than i'll write something like this:
T x = m.at<T>(2,3);

// How to get T from the deferred template?
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, I've added more code example in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `type` member to your `MatFactory`:

```
template <typename T, T V>
class MatFactory {
public:
    typedef T type;
   ...
};
```

Note that non-type template arguments are rather limited. In particular, floating point types are not allowed (thinking of it this may have been changed with C++2011).

Comment: No, that hasn't changed in C++11. Non-type parameters can still only be of integral, enumeration, pointer, _lvalue_ reference, or pointer-to-member type.

Comment: So, If I add `typedef T type` member, I can write than: `MF.type m.at<MF.type>(2,3)` in my example above?

Comment: Not quite but nearly: you would use `MF::type` if this is not in a template or if `MF` does not depend on a template parameter. Otherwise you'd need to use `typename MF::type`.

Answer (score 1):

> If you know the array element type (which can be retrieved using the method Mat::type() ), you can access the element M_{ij} of a 2-dimensional array as:
>
> > `M.at<double>(i,j) += 1.f;`
>
> assuming that M is a double-precision floating-point array. There are several variants of the method at for a different number of dimensions.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat